# How to solve the following limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{2^2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{3^2}\bigg) \cdots \bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg)}$$

This simplifies to $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\cfrac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}}$.
Besides partial fractions and telescope, how else can we solve? Thank you!

Comment: Using the fact $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$

Comment: $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}{\cfrac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n^2}}$. A further hint?

Comment: I suppose there are typo's in your product formula.

Comment: Yes. Expanding the product it's the key to observe that they simplify each other. Thank you!

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{2^2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{3^2}\bigg) \cdots \bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{3}\bigg) \cdots \bigg(1-\cfrac{1}{n}\bigg)\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{3}\bigg) \cdots \bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{n}\bigg)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\frac{n+1}2\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}